# Is it possible to install a guest operating system from USB on virtualbox?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Oracle Virtualbox 4.0.4 Fedora 14

I have installed Oracle Virtualbox on my Fedora 14. Now I want to install windows as a guest. However, I have enabled USB support. But on the system menu there isn't an option to boot from the USB. I have created a bootable windows installation on my USB.

As I am running on a netbook without any DVD/CD drive, my only option it to install from the USB.

Is this possible?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: answer: yes....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no GUI option to boot from a USB drive, but VirtualBox provides a script that'll let you do it. See this link for a tutorial: http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/

The tutorial is for Windows, but the Virtual Box tools they use are the same.

Comment: An easier solution is to mount the *.iso to the CD/DVD drive. Under settings select the CD/DVD, then select the *.iso. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

VirtualBox IS able to load from USB! However it is a bit tricky.
I was not able to boot from USB in BIOS mode, so enable the EFI mode!
[image: Enable EFI]

Now add the wanted USB device to the config to automatically mount it on start
[image: Add USB to VM]

Now start machine
If the USB-drive is already detected, skip this step (the reset). However on some systems unfortunately right after start the USB-Stick might not be detected:
[image: first boot attempt]

make sure that USB is connected:
[image: check USB is attached]

If there is a general issue to mount an USB drive to a VM, see this post [VirtualBox Error: USB device is busy with the previous request](https://superuser.com/a/1137064/501970).
Now reset the machine (not power off) using the menu or hit <kbd>Hostkey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (ususally Hostkey is <kbd>RightCTRL</kbd>).
You might be lucky and the system is already booting from USB. If not you need to provide the boot file manually. To do this you should now see an additional drive (here FS0: - no other drives are attached to my VM). If there is a vdi attached (this is always detected, probably as FS0:), you might find a new like FS1:
[image: specify boot file]

First type the 'drive' to boot from, here `FS0:`.
Next you need to specify the efi-file, you can also use 'ls' or 'cd' commands to browse the folders on the USB drive. Provide file name (usually located below 'EFI') e.g. `efi\boot\bootx64.efi`.
Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot from that EFI boot file.
It is possible to store this info permanently into the file startup.nsh, see  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326957) for a good explanation.
As an alternative type 'exit' + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to leave the shell and enter the EFI Menu. Now choose 'Boot Manager':
[image]

Select the drive to boot from. There are more options in the EFI settings like providing a path to the efi file manually. Unfortunately these settings are not stored permanently in NVRAM of the VM (VBox 7.06).

If you want to enter this menu directly, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> immeditaly when the VM starts. The timing here is critical, it took me some attempts (resetting machine and try again).

Comment: Thanks, great answer!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it is not possible to Boot from USB in VirtualBOX, no mather what else says, it is not possible, VirtualBOX boot menu does not have USB.

What is posible is to emulate a Virtual Hard Disk based on data being on the USB (called RAW disk access, VMDK, ...)... but that is not boot form USB it is boot from a SATA/IDE device that reads/writes data from/to the USB.
This procedure is what is implied in the link of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/267683/245595) (as of this writing, the accepted one).

Sometimes you need to do a real boot from USB... that is not yet possible on VirtualBOX.

Ah, there is a "Not FAKE" video on YouTube showing a screen of VirtualBOX with USB option on its BIOS / UEFI implementation... that version was created and compiled by some guy but just for one specific USB device (the one used on the video), it is not a general USB boot (neither code is included on VirtualBOX); it will serve as a 1st proof of concept that at least it would be possible to implement USB boot, but it is still not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to boot from USB and install in another hard drive. After you initially added a Virtual disk for the USB using http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/ then before you start the VM, you can add more HDD using the Storage option. And while booting, using F12 we can get two controller options. We can select the one for USB for booting and then from within the booted OS, we can choose the other HDD that is detected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, but not from USB. You need to do that from hard drive.

First you need to make bootable ISO file. I have used Imgburn, it's a good and free program. After that you need to copy that ISO file onto a hard drive in your computer where you want to install guest in VirtualBox. I put it on the desktop.

Then start up VirtualBox and go to Settings → Storage. You will see "IDE Controller/empty" option. Click on empty disk to mark it. On the right side you will see Attributes, CD/DVD option. Choose "IDE Secondary master".

Then click on disk icon on the right and click on "Choose a virtual CD/DVD file...". A window will open, choose your bootable ISO file and click OK at bottom right. Then go to your VirtualBox start menu, select the virtual drive you made and click Start. It will run the installation.

This way I have installed Windows 7 as a guest on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

Not the exact topic, but if you want to install a second Windows in your Virtual Machine it is easy.

If have a Virtual Machine Make in VirtualBox:

1. Resize the Main Partition with EaseUs Partition Master or Similar.
2. When Finished the Process of the Resize Init the VirtualBox Machine, and With EaseUs Partition Master or Similar Create New Partition in the Space Free and Format.
3. When Finished all the Process of Resize, Create a New Partition and Formatting, Exit of VirtualBox Machine.
4. Select the VirtualVBox Machine in the Main Window of VirtualBox, Right Click, Select Menu Configuration, go to Storage, and there is Possible to Add an ISO How CD-ROM.
5. Run the Virtual Machine and Press <kbd>F12</kbd>, Select the Option to Run from CD-ROM, and Install the Windows you have in the ISO how CD-ROM.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked.